# Have an Alert Box Display on Opening a PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe, alert

I want to create a PDF that will bring up a typical "OK/Cancel" alert box when the user opens it. Ideally, this would be built into the PDF, so it could be downloaded and passed around without losing the alert box.

Is this possible to do under current Adobe PDF standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be possible:

[The Alert Box: Part 1 of 5 on Popup Windows](http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/popup_windows_part1)