# create pop up window programmatically in pdf with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, itext

I would like to create pop window in pdf, where the user require to input the data such as email and password to decrypt the pdf file.

How to create pop-up window in pdf?

Comment: Have you looked at the PDF specification? https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html If you just want to do it in AdobeAcrobat, there is plenty of end user documentation and tutorials available on the web.

Comment: If the PDF is encrypted then the commands to "pop up a window" will be encrypted, too. Do you actually want to create a web page that asks for this information and then passes those to the PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat has several types of built-in Popup Windows (alert, response, and file open), as well as functions for creating custom dialogs.

http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/popup_windows_part1

[Have an Alert Box Display on Opening a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127596/have-an-alert-box-display-on-opening-a-pdf)